# When was “Checked” added and who added it - SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

I'm beginning to study SQL queries and attempting to understand some more difficult ones. I have these 2 tables:

User

```
ID_user
Name
```

Tracking

```
ID_Track
Old_Value
New_Value
Date_Entered
ID_user
```

The data entry interface looks like this:

```
User                        Column       Date            Old Value            New Value
David (assistant)           Status       02/2022         Pending              Processing
David (assistant)           address      02/2022         Miami                New York City
David (assistant)           Type         02/2022         House                Apartment
David(assistant)            Size         02/2022         Small                Big
Peter(QA)                   Size         06/2022          -                   Medium 
Peter(QA)                   Status       06/2022          -                   Checked
```

I'm trying to figure out how to join User and Tracking tables in order to know when the word “Checked” was added and who added it.

Comment: Hi - I suggest  you take one of the many online SQL tutorials where you will learn about joins. Just make sure it teaches ANSI SQL join syntax and not the Oracle join syntax that was deprecated 30+ years ago

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Right now you are essentially asking us to (re)write a textbook with bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> know when the word *Checked* was added and who added it

You can filter the `tracking` table for the keyword, and then bring the user name with a `join` on the `user` table:

```
select t.*, u.name
from tracking t
inner join user u on u.id_user = t.id_user
where t.new_value = 'Checked'
```

You  can add more conditions in the `where` clause if you need more filtering criteria.

Comment: Gracias totales, it works.